# What does "Keyword not supported: 'endpoint'" mean and how does it relate to the "messaging" connectionstring?

Tags: azure, configuration

I'm encountering the following issue but can't find any documentation to troubleshoot this issue. Any tips?

```
51324 09:55:20 ERROR Messaging : IMessageBus failed to start 'Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Messaging.Buses.PurgeFromCampaignMessagesBus'.
Exception: Rebus.Injection.ResolutionException
Message: Could not resolve Rebus.Transport.ITransport with decorator depth 0 - registrations: Rebus.Injection.Injectionist+Handler
Source: Rebus
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   at Rebus.Config.RebusConfigurer.<>c.<Start>b__12_12(IResolutionContext c)
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   at Rebus.Config.RebusConfigurer.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Start>b__25(IResolutionContext c)
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   at Rebus.Config.RebusConfigurer.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Start>b__26(IResolutionContext c)
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.Rebus.OptionsConfigurerExtensions.<>c.<DecorateUsingRetryerBus>b__0_0(IResolutionContext ctx)
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.Get[TService]()
   at Rebus.Config.RebusConfigurer.Start()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.MessageServiceBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_3.<AddBuses>b__3(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.MessageBusRegistry.EnsureIsStarted(String busName)
   at Sitecore.Messaging.MessageBusStarter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Start>b__0()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: Keyword not supported: 'endpoint'.
Source: System.Data
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential)
   at Rebus.SqlServer.DbConnectionProvider.CreateSqlConnectionSuppressingAPossibleAmbientTransaction()
   at Rebus.SqlServer.DbConnectionProvider.<GetConnection>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Rebus.SqlServer.Transport.SqlServerTransport.<InnerEnsureTableIsCreatedAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Rebus.SqlServer.Transport.SqlServerTransport.<EnsureTableIsCreatedAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Rebus.SqlServer.AsyncHelpers.CustomSynchronizationContext.<<Run>b__7_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Rebus.SqlServer.AsyncHelpers.CustomSynchronizationContext.Run()
   at Rebus.SqlServer.AsyncHelpers.RunSync(Func`1 task)
   at Rebus.SqlServer.Transport.SqlServerTransport.EnsureTableIsCreated()
   at Rebus.Config.SqlServerTransportConfigurationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Configure>b__0(IResolutionContext context)
   at Rebus.Injection.Injectionist.ResolutionContext.Get[TService]()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a "messaging" connection string like the following:

```
Endpoint=sb://mc-{GUID}-asb.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey={SOME_KEY}
```

There is a related setting called `messagingTransport:define`. You may often see it configured with **SQL** like the following:

```
<add key="messagingTransport:define" value="SQL" />
```

Change the value to **AzureServiceBus** and then make sure your firewall is not blocking the connection.

#### Resources

- I learned of this setting from [this article by Joao Neto](https://joaoneto.blog/2020/08/07/understanding-sitecore-logs-part-5-thread-pool-size-monitor-rebus-assembly-resolver-mvc-area-registration-and-xml-configuration-load/).
- I then used the [ServiceBusExplorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) tool to validate that I can connect.